# read text file with ip address list and make a curl connection

Tags: python

i'm tying to create a python script that reads a text file with a list of ip addresses then would send a curl request to port 80 and supply a user name and password to see if I can log into the web interface and return whatever the web page displays. any help is most appreciated.

```
import sys
import requests

f = open('APs.txt', 'r')
c = f.read()
for i in c:
    r = requests.get('http://' + i, auth=('user', 'pass'))
    print(i, r.status_code)
f.close()
```

Comment: It's more helpful to show what you've already tried, and ask for help with debugging specific issues.

Comment: would need to know how the username and password are actually sent to the remote server

Comment: Here is what I have so far:

Comment: And what problems do you have with this code?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is working as expected.  Does anyone have a better way?

```
import sys
import requests

with open(r'APs.txt', 'r') as ips:
    for line in ips:
        ip = line.strip()
        r = requests.get('http://' +ip, auth=('user', 'pass'))
        print(ip,',',r.status_code)
```

This is what I have now but I am getting a error and trying to work with try/except but having issues.

```
import sys
import requests

with open(r'APs.txt', 'r') as ips:
    for line in ips:
        try:
            ip = line.strip()
            r = requests.get('http://' +ip, auth=('user', 'pass'), timeout=2)
            print(ip,',',r.status_code)
        except ConnectTimeout:
            print(ip,',','error')
```

here is the error:
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='1.1.1.1', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to 1.1.1.1 timed out. (connect timeout=1)'))

Comment: how would I handle exception errors if one of the ip address in my list is invalid?

Comment: you might want to add a parameter `timeout=some_value` so you don't sit around waiting forever...

Comment: how to I find the exception error name to use with try/except?  this is what I am getting: requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='1.1.1.1', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001E8877AFE08>, 'Connection to 1.1.1.1 timed out. (connect timeout=1)'))

Comment: Is anyone able to help out with dealing with errors?  I'm stuck.